# Implement uploading of screencast

Tags: feature-request

Will askubuntu implement uploading of screencasts ?  I think screencasts are better way to show the errors or problems users might encounter.

Comment: This has been talked about before.  There was some note about a screen capture to animated gif utility.  It's on main somewhere.

Comment: If want to participate in making answers that awesome, you should check out this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast

Comment: Sorry I didn't find about screencast on meta so I asked this question.

Comment: @M the downvote wasn't me, but that is how you get screencasts in to stackexchange.

Comment: Ok I got it. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Downvotes don't mean the same on meta as they do on main.  I'ld just leave it as is, or post a self answer about how you found out you can already do this with animated gifs and accept it.

Comment: @M.Tarun, I think this question should be deleted, because it's basically a duplicate of that "How to create screencast" question. At first, the question seemed to me about "integrating AskUbuntu with screencasts" somehow, as like, a "button" to capture a screencast. But the whole point of your question was to just take a screencast. So this question is like stranded in the middle, it's about AskUbuntu itself, but then the answer makes this question not belong here on meta =). It can either be moved to the main AskUbuntu site and marked as a duplicate, or just deleted. I hope you understand.

Comment: @Alaa My point is "integrating AskUbuntu with screencasts" somehow, as like, a "button" to capture a screencast.

Answer (score 0):

First install this:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick mplayer gtk-recordmydesktop
```

those are the required stuff, ImageMagick, MPlayer and Desktop Recorder.
Then use **Desktop Recorder** to capture a portion of the screen/application to use as the screencast.  After the Desktop Recorder has saved the recording into an **OGV video**, **MPlayer** will be used to capture JPEG screenshots, saving them into the 'output' directory.

On a terminal:

```
mplayer -ao null <video file name> -vo jpeg:outdir=output
```

Use **ImageMagick** to convert the screenshots into an animated gifs.

```
convert output/* output.gif
```

you can optimize the screenshots this way:

```
convert output.gif -fuzz 10% -layers Optimize optimised.gif
```

**SOURCE:** [how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast)